# Groovy for loop with multiple counters?

Tags: groovy

Following works in groovy -

```
for(def i=0;i<10;i++)
    print i
```

But this which is valid in Java, C++ does not work in groovy -

```
for(def i=0,j=0;i<10;i++,j++)
    print i + ' ' + j
```

Why? How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

It will not working as Groovy does not accept multiple expressions in a [for loop](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping).
Try this:

```
[0..10,0..10].transpose().each{ i, j ->
    println i + ' ' + j
}
```

to achieve the same result.

Update to make it more generalized. This update is equivalent to increment with `i++`, `j+=3`.

```
(0..<10).collect{[it, it+3]}.each{ i, j ->
    println i + ' ' + j
}
```

Comment: What if I need to do i++ and j+=3

Comment: wasn't the desired result [0,0], [1, 3], [2, 6]...? (0..<10).collect{[it, it + 3]} returns [0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
for( def ( int i, int j ) = [ 0, 0 ]; i < 10; i++, j++ )
```

If that doesn't work, it might be failing because of the last part.

C++ has a explicit comma operator, which is how it allows constructs like this.

Java does not have a comma operator, but presumably allows constructs such as this as a hack to the for loop.

If Groovy wont allow this, it's most probably because it doesn't allow this hack.